# Shape analysis of an object to create features for pattern recognition

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I am currently with a medical imaging project. Just wondering how to measure the shape of a sphere. For example, how to give a measurement that an object is more like a sphere than the other?

I know some algorithm can give the 'roundness' in 2D, but a measure of 'sphereness' in 3D would be more helpful.

Also, I am very interested in other shape analysis. The shape of the object could be a very interesting feature for further pattern recognition.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods, that e.g. compute the outline of the object, and compute the distance from the centroid at various angles.

Look up **feature extraction from images** in various books an publications. There are *tons* of methods around.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison the methods:
Yang Mingqiang, Kpalma Kidiyo, Ronsin Joseph, "A survey of shape feature extraction techniques," July 15, 2008

OpenCV Library:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a measure similar to roundness, which answers the question how likely something is to a sphere. It is called [Sphericity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericity)

> Sphericity is a measure of how spherical (round) an object is. As
>   such, it is a specific example of a compactness measure of a shape.
>   Defined by Wadell in 1935, the sphericity, of a particle is:
>   the ratio of the surface area of a sphere (with the same volume as the
>   given particle) to the surface area of the particle.